# Elegant way to extend MDLAsset to support importing new formats

Tags: swift

I was wondering what would be an elegant way, in Swift, to make MDLAsset to support to other 3D model files than the default ones.

My best finding is to use a factory method like this:

```
extension MDLAsset {
    static func makeAssetFromEXTFile(atUrl: URL) -> MDLAsset { … }
}
```

Of course I thought about overriding initialisers but since there are many of them I don't really know if that's the right way to go...

Do you think my factory function method is good? Do you see any other elegant solution? :)

Thank you